# Confusion regarding frequent updates of instanced array using glBufferSubData

Tags: c++, opengl, buffer, gpu

I'm rendering large patches of grass using instanced rendering and for that I use an instanced array consisting of a large number of 4x4 transformation matrices.

I use a LOD algorithm on the grass leaves to determine which leaves to render based on their distance to the camera. For this reason I update the instanced array to only contain the relevant transformation matrices and then render their respective leaves via `glDrawArraysInstanced`.

My confusion comes with updating the instanced array. I create the instanced array once as follows:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_Models);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, grass.size() * sizeof(glm::vec4), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
```

Then the most efficient approach would be to use `glBufferSubData` to update its content (to save expensive memory re-allocations) which I do as follows:

```
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, grassModels.size() * sizeof(glm::mat4), &grassModels[0]);
```

But here's where things get weird. If I use `glBufferSubData` it only seems to update the instanced arrays during rendering after I move a certain distance around the scene (I'd say around every 1000 frames) and not if I remain static at the same position.

It does work perfectly as soon as I re-allocate the memory with `glBufferData`. So I figured it might be a syncrhonization issue so I implemented a round-robin approach with multiple buffers; didn't work. I tried orphaning which did work (since I again use `glBufferData`) but I'd prefer not to use this approach.

Synchronization issues however should usually only occur over a few frames (and not around a 1000 in my case, only after movement). Maybe movement is involved, because that significantly changes the buffer's content, forcing the GPU to use the newly updated memory?

I'm not sure what's causing this behavior of `glBufferSubData` and couldn't find anything similar to my issue in the docs. I can easily fix the issue using `glBufferData` which doesn't give me a noticable performance decrease, but I'm quite curious as to what is causing this behavior?

Comment: does glMapBuffer work?

Comment: I haven't tried `glMapBuffer` yet, but that shouldn't explain the behavior I'm noticing here between `glBufferData` and `glBufferSubData` right? I'll try it out anyways and see if it gives similar results

Comment: I think it may be because you allocate with sizeof(glm::vec4) while you update with sizeof(glm::mat4)

Comment: Yep you're right, I feel like an idiot; hours of debugging and reading GL docs and it was so simple. Using `glMapBuffer` indeed crashed after I reached a certain treshold of grass leaves leading me to the fault. Thanks for being the second pair of eyes that I appareantly needed here ;)

Comment: This also explains why it only occured after movement. During movement, it only updates the buffer when the surrounding grass leaves fit inside the allocated memory, which it didn't always do. You can either answer the question if you feel like it or I'll answer it myself in the next hour. Thanks, once again

Comment: Just as a side note, I've read that orphaning the buffer is the best idea anyway, in the absence of fences (extensions).  I'm not sure drivers even pay attention to GL_STREAM_DRAW.  At least they don't have to do they.  It's just a hint.  You might want to revisit this when glNext comes around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_Models);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, grass.size() * sizeof(glm::vec4), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
```

The size passed in here is smaller than the size you are updating. This leads to GL_INVALID_VALUE​ and turns the update into a noop.